# Manual syncing of files each time it changes (between a desktop always connected home-wifi and a laptop that I carry around)

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, inotify, kde-neon

I know I have to use inotifywatch or something for this. I also know I can use rsync. I know that my connection should be made through SSH for better security but here's what I don't know: Where to start

I want to implement a logic like this:

on my laptop

```c
if (any of the file in the watched folder (locally on my laptop) changes && the laptop is connected to my home wifi && my desktop is accessible through SSH) {
    run rsync and and some ssh command to access my desktop and update the folder on my desktop
}
```

on my desktop

```c
if (any of the file changes in the watched folder (locally on my desktop) and my laptop is accessible with SSH) {
    run rsync and and some ssh command to access my laptop and update the folder on my laptop
}
```

I am using a KDE Neon installation of both the machines with an (almost) identical setup.

Comment: Have you considered Syncthing?

Comment: Your logic is incomplete. If laptop and desktop have modified the same file differently, what should you do?

Comment: Use a file sharing service to have a shared folder. You can find Gigabytes for free. Dropbox, etc

Comment: @waltinator Dropbox only had 2 gigs in their free plan and I would need more than that. But apart from that, could you help me fix the logic or give suggestions.

Comment: https://syncthing.net/

Comment: @they I will check it out but I think it requires one of my PCs to always be on

Comment: @SbeveSbren Hmmm... To run `rsync` between two hosts, you require both hosts to be running. I don't see your point.

Comment: hmm true can rcloud help me auto sync stuff with google drive?